# Re-initialise the dataframe did not work in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and I am trying to re-initialise the dataframe using the pd.DataFrame constructor with dtype=object. This is because the column from excel is reading it as float instead of integer. When I try to change it to object, the data seems the same. It still showing as float. The datatype have changed to object but the data did not change to the original number. Below is the code and screenshot of the output:

```
df = pd.read_csv (filename , low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df['C9_O1'].head(165))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype=object)
print(df['C9_O1'].head(165))
```

[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74914400/5235168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
This replaces nan/ missing value with 0 and float values with int.

```py
df = pd.read_csv (filename , low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df['C9_O1'].head(165))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, dtype=object)

print(df['C9_O1'].head(165))
df["C9_O1"] = df["C9_O1"].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: hmm but some other columns contains decimal numbers too. If I convert into int, wouldnt it affect the decimal numbers?

Comment: this code only applies to C9_O1 column as per your question.

Comment: i tried the code and i got an error: KeyError: "None of [Index(['C', '9', '_', 'O', '1'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Comment: I have updated teh code pls try now

Comment: it works. Thank you. Can you help if some of the columns are in decimal? Because i just tried to work with 1

Comment: yes sure, you can post a new question with the csv file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914655/how-to-re-initialise-the-dataframe-to-integer-and-decimal-from-float-for-multipl