# How to Re-initialise the dataframe to integer and decimal from float for multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the dataframe to integer and decimal based on the columns. However, I want to do it without specifying the column names as there are many columns. For now, I have converted a float to integer but when I use this code, it also converts the columns with decimal into integer. Below is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv (filename , low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df.head(165))
df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype('int')
print(df.head(165))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can u provide a sample of csv file

Comment: i will attach a csv file here

Comment: can use gdrive or temp file upload service like https://tmpfiles.org/

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/dl/515427/sampledata.csv There are two columns which are identified as float at beginning. But I need to convert the integer value as integer and remain the float as decimal value without specifying the column names in dataframe as the column names might change in future. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: hi @GuneshShanbhag did you found any solution for this? Sorry for troubling you

Comment: hi @Sriram check this answer if this solves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921123/5235168

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to convert the dataframe to integer and decimal based on the columns. However, I want to do it without specifying the column names as there are many columns.

If you are trying to convert the dataframe to integer and decimal based on the columns, its Best to provide the column names to have a control on which columns are needed to be chnaged with another data types.

1. You can specify which columns you want to change to some other data type

You can run to get data types of all the columns

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Then

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./sampledata.csv", low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df.head(165))

df[["C9_O1", "Variety #1_B15"]] = df[["C9_O1", "Variety #1_B15"]].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df.head(165))
```

Provide desired column type in astype function. I ahve added int to convert float to int for these 2 columns.

2. If you want some columns to be altered to decimal and some to int
   Then you can create a dictionary of dtypes.
   Run to display dtypes of all column in df.

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Here I am creating a dictionary with each column name as key and its data type as its value.
Then you can provide desired datatypes to which the df column should be altered to. Here, I wanted to convert C9_01 column to int hence i have provided it. After that you can provide the dictionary to as type function and it will do the rest

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./sampledata.csv", low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
# print(df.dtypes)
dtypes_dict = {df.columns[index]: dtype for index, dtype in enumerate(df.dtypes)}
print(dtypes_dict)

print(type(dtypes_dict["C9_O1"]))

dtypes_dict["C9_O1"] = np.int16

print(df.head(165))
df = df.fillna(0).astype(dtypes_dict)
print(df.head(165))
```